# How to implement an enum which is needed in two different classes?

Tags: java, enums

Class `Action`:

```
public class Action {
    public static enum Type {
        POSITION, MOUSE, KEY, TEXT
    }

    public final Type type;

    public Action() {
        this.type = Type.KEY;
    }

    //properties, getters, setters ...
}
```

Class `Model`:

```
public class Model {
    public static enum Type {
        POSITION, MOUSE, KEY, TEXT
    }

    public final Type type;

    public void doSomething() {
        Action action = new Action();
        switch (action.type) {
            case this.Type.POSITION: //cannot convert from Model.Type to Action.Type
                //do stuff here
                break;
            case ...
                //more stuff here
                break;
            default:
                //default stuff here
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

This was my (simplified) initial approach which obviously doesn't work. The Model needs to do some operation, dependent on what `Type` the `Action` has and I would like to determine that without having to cross borders between the two classes, meaning I hope there is a better solution than the following:

```
Action.Type type = action.type;
```

Comment: You can just one enum and access it directly. For example, if you keep only the enum inside Action, you can do `private final Action.Type type;` in Model

Comment: @MarcoAcierno  Why do you write the answer as a comment?

Comment: Probably because it's not a very nice solution. At least, I don't like it for the very reason I put in the question, namely crossing class borders.

Comment: @jaySon Not really, I think it's the correct way to do it in your case. It gives context to the enum. Can you tell me what is/what means the enum Type in his own Type.java file? Can you tell me what is/what means Type inside the Action class? "The type of the action" but with Type.java you can only tell me "It's a Type". The more your codebase grows, the more you will appreciate that kind of "implicit explanation"

Comment: Putting the enum `Type` in its own `Type.java` means creating a `.java` file with only that very enum inside. No class, no methods whatsoever. Using the Action class' `Type` enum outside the Action class, means (in my eyes) violating the concept of information hiding, because the Model's dependency on the Action class is then hardcoded and that makes the code very unflexible for future changes. So the exact opposite of your conclusion would happen, namely the more your codebase grows, the more problems you will have changing things related to this hardcoded dependency.

Comment: The enum Type has a reason to exists only in your Action class, right? (I think I'm missing/You're missing your/my point) It's the `Type` of `Action`, you will use it when you need to refer to the Type of the Action right? If you use it in a generic way, you could end up with an enum with a lot of constants. There is a dependency between Type and Action, making Type move the enum on his own file will just hide it from yourself

Comment: I'm using the `Action.Type` in all three components - Model, View and Controller. Thinking about what you wrote actually makes me believe you're right about leaving `Type` in the `Action` class for the reasons you described.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must extract the enum into a separated source file, like a class but with a type 'enum' :

```
public enum Type {
    POSITION, 
    MOUSE, 
    KEY, 
    TEXT
}
```

and access it into your classes by importing it.

You can also keep the enum into one of your class with static keyword, and access to it in the another class by adding an import statement

Comment: If you put the enum into an interface and implement this interface by both classes you are not crossing borders between classes (apart from importing the interface).